# preposition choice: vary in/with

Tags: prepositions

Are the following sentences both correct? If so, what's the difference?

> The disease varies with severity.

> The disease varies in severity.

Comment: When we say X varies ***with*** Y, we mean that whenever Y changes, X also changes. For example, *The prognosis for Covid varies **with age*** (because it usually affects older people different to younger people). But X varies ***in*** Y means there is some characteristic (Y) that occurs in a range of different forms among instances of X. For example, *The disease varies **in severity*** (in part, *...depending on how old you are*).

Answer (score 1):

**Varies in severity** means the severity of the disease is not constant. It varies.

**Varies with** usually means that something varies according to something else. For example,
*The severity of the disease varies with the age of the sufferer.*

It is strange to say that a **disease varies with severity**. I would even say that that example doesn't make sense.

Comment: How about "The symptoms of the disease vary with its severity"?

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: Clutching at straws, *The prognosis for the disease varies with severity of economic hardship* (people suffering from severe economic hardship often have a different outcome).